# Excel: how to insert a hyphen for blank rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know you can insert a hyphen for a blank cells, but I can't insert a hyphen for multiple cells that are blank. Excel does not seem to have a feature for that, but has one for one blank cell.

Can someone please help me? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

(I put the hyphens manually just as an example)

Comment: Is `column F` a formula or just numbers?

Comment: Column F is a formula

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select fields, press `CTRL+G` (goto) `Special`, select `Blanks`, type `-` then press `CTRL+ENTER`.

**EDIT:**

As OP clarified that Column F is a formula, try this:

`=IF(SUM(C2:E2)=0,"-",SUM(C2:E2))`

Comment: I never knew you could do that...thanks for sharing!

Comment: What if I have a dataset of over 1000? I can't select fields from such a large dataset..

Comment: Select everything... `CTRL+A` then do above steps.

Comment: What if I just want to put one hyphen for every multiple blank rows? What I mean is not put hyphen for every cell that is blank. Sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: @user112947 Not sure what you mean... Any chance you can add screenshot or link to an image?

Comment: Thanks so much! So I can just drag it down to full in for the entire dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

Select ColumnF, HOME > Cells – Format, Format Cells…, Custom, in the Type: box enter:

```
General;-General;-
```

then click OK.

> A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.
>
> POSITIVE;NEGATIVE;ZERO;TEXT

[ref](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx)

Comment: This converts cells with `0` value to blanks, not hyphens?

Comment: I had to Google for the [meaning of "TQ"](http://www.internetslang.com/TQ-meaning-definition.asp) :)

Answer (score 1):

Type an apostrophe then the hyphen like this " '- " and the apostrophe disappears, but the hyphen stays.